# Bigger fonts on smaller screens without @media queries or javascript?

Tags: css, fonts, calc

Is there an alternative for @media queries to accomplish font-size inversely proportional to the screen size? (e.g.: opposite effect of `2vw`, where the font gets smaller on small screens);

My first try was divide a value by a viewport width increment, but `font-size: calc(10vw / 2);` works while `font-size: calc(100 / 2vw);` unfortunately doesn't works.

[**codepen of my first try**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMpdXg?editors=1100)

Comment: because you can't divide by "not a number". Dividing a dimension value by a number works because 10vw, divided by two, is necessarily 5vw. However, what would dividing 10 by 2vw do? The result would be 5/vw, or "5 times the value 1/vw", which makes no sense.

Comment: thanks for the comment, Mike; its more clear now. My objective was use the `calc()` method to let the font size inversely proportional to the screen size (font bigger on mobile, smaller on desktops) but seems like it's impossible on this way.

Comment: What do you want the final value to be... 50vw???

Comment: No, I was thinking in something like... 50vw of a 1000px screen means 500px; while 50vw of a 500px screen means 250px; So a number divided by a vw increment would be smaller on big screens.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with that - do you want the font to get smaller, the larger the screen is? (is there a reason why absolute units like `in` or `cm` wouldn't work there?)

Comment: yes, can you give me an example, please? I mean, a `calc()` one without to use @media queries.

Comment: Why would you ever want to avoid media queries? This is literally what they are for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't divide a `px` value by a viewport-width increment, but you can achieve this inverse size behavior **reducing** a `px` value by a viewport-width increment.

*Example:*
`font-size: calc(40px - 2vw);`

[**Codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/dMWOLd)

Alternatively, you could use the other 3 units related to the viewport's size: `vh` `vmin` and `vmax`.

*Examples:*
`font-size: calc(40px - 2vh);`
`font-size: calc(200px - 20vmin);`
`font-size: calc(200px - 20vmax);`

> **vw** - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*;
>   **vh** - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*;
>   **vmin** - Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension;
>   **vmax** - Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension;
>
> ***viewport** = the browser window size.
>
> Source: [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: I found this solution just right now. Anyway, there's still an open bounty on the question so new ideas/infos are welcome.

Comment: The advantage with my answer would be that you can have a min/max size, and with a very small performance hit, as it only target one item.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a vw is 1/100th of the width of the viewport. That's it. 2vw = 2/100ths of the screen. There is no way to get it to be inversely proportional because math doesn't work that way. I am assuming you are doing this as a thought experiment, rather than trying to solve a problem in your code so I'm going to leave it at that.

You could calculate the size of the font to be inversely proportional via javascript. [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNvGgo)

HTML:

```
<div >
    This is text
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    area = 50000;
    width = $(window).width();
    fontSize= (Math.ceil(area/width));
    $('div').css('font-size', fontSize);
    }).resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best that you can do is to use a font size that is not relative to a viewport. For example, `1em` will be relatively large on a mobile device and will relatively small on a desktop client. If you use a fluid layout, `em` is perfect. If you use a static layout, your best option would probably be `px`. But using `px` is a bit iffy because a mobile device could potentially have just as many pixels as a desktop client.

The reason that `calc(10vw / 2)` works but `calc(100 / 2vw)` doesn't is because the former evaluates to `5vw` and the latter evaluates to `50/vw` which isn't an expression of distance. More precisely, the engine can only divide by scalar

In summation, to do what you want to do, you'll need to have a fluid layout and use `em` as your unit for font sizes. But you won't be able to get a direct ratio of the size of the viewport without JavaScript, which you should of course generally not rely on for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script solution (even if you wanted, and found, a CSS only), though this one impact the performance very little and only need to run once per resize and for one element only, the body.

It has one benefit over CSS, you can have a min/max size, and works as a progressive enhancement for users that have script enabled so in a way risk free.

```js
var fontMax = 40, fontMin = 14;

function sizeBodyFont() {
  var fontSize = ((screen.width / window.innerWidth) * 10);
  document.body.style.fontSize = Math.min(Math.max(fontSize,fontMin),fontMax) + 'px';
}

sizeBodyFont();

(function(el) {
  window.addEventListener('resize', sizeBodyFont);  
}(document.querySelector('#test')))
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}
span {
  font-size: 100%;
}
div {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<span>Hey there</span>
<div>Hey there</div>
```

Comment: **bounty reasons**: **a**) plain javascript is more than the goal (css-only) but is lighter than jQuery. **b**) the wrong information was striked and the answer is updated **c**) the example on the snippet works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using css [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp)

Here is an awesome github project that can help you: https://clamp.font-size.app/

You'll need to switch the values for max & min to make it work, see example:

```css
body {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 5.1241rem + -5.6206vw, 4rem);
}
```

```html
<p>I scale at smaller viewport widths!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative font-styling. like -

```
html, body {
font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2.5em;
}

p {
font-size: 1em;
}
```