# Increase height as width decreases(Reverse Vw for height)

Tags: html, css

i have been trying to increase the height of a div as the width decreases. This allows for all the text to fit in better and not flow out. Is it possible to achieve this without js?

```
    width: 100%;
    height: 29vw;
```

Vw decreases the height as the width decreases.(i need the exact opposite behaviour. Width goes down-height goes up) I have tried using a negative vw to reverse the effect with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main way to do it is using CSS media queries (wich is very popular). If you're looking for an alternative to do it without media queries, here it is:

`vw` gets bigger on small screens while `calc(Xpx - Xvw)` gets smaller on small screens.

Example:

```
div {
  width: 40vw;
  height: calc(400px - 20vw);
  background: tomato;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L699fLp2/)

Alternatively, you could use the other 3 units related to the viewport's size: `vh` `vmin` and `vmax`.

> **vw** - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*;
>   **vh** - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*;
>   **vmin** - Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension;
>   **vmax** - Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension;
>
> ***viewport** = the browser window size.
>
> Source: [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: I did find this "trick" when I was looking for an answer to [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35978790/5875416)