# How can I stop my text breaking up when resizing browser while maintaining a constant distance to the edge of the browser?

Tags: css, media-queries

[Webpage resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBCYB.jpg)

Would I need to simply add a lot more media query max-min width sizes or is there a better way?

Comment: do not share external links. Write here the code that replicates your problem and what have you tried to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are your safest bet, and though time consuming, are very effective. You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36173212) particularly helpful. You can  reduce a px value by a viewport-width increment.

Comment: I am adding in more media queries but it doesn't seem to be affecting anything between the browser sizes I showed in the photo, would you mind taking a quick look? https://codepen.io/alex-burger/pen/Jvexxd